# Not getting the type safety of generics and when to use generics

Tags: c#, generics

I'm unclear on the differences between

```
public class MyVehicleCollection<T> where T : Vehicle
{
     private List<T> listofVehicles = new List<T>();

     public void AddVehicle(T v) { listofVehicles.Add(v); }
}
```

and

```
public class MyVehicleCollection<Vehicle>
{
     private List<Vehicle> listofVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

     public void AddVehicle(Vehicle v) { listofVehicles.Add(v); }
}
```

I don't see why in both cases its only possible to add types derived from Vehicle to the collection. I also don't see why i'd need to create additional collection classes for containing Motobike : Vehicle in the non-generic case.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You trade some extensibility which might or might not be needed or expected in the future. Sure you could add bikes in the future but are you ever going to do that? Depending on the future you can create a closed or open architecture.

Comment: It seems your confusion is caused by the fact that you're using `Vehicle` both as a generic type parameter and as a class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second form is not bound to Vehicle at all:

```
public class MyVehicleCollection<Vehicle>
{
}

...

var coll = new MyVehicleCollection<string>();
```

From your description, you don't seem to need generics at all.

```
public class MyPlainVehicleCollection  //<Vehicle>  no Type Parameter
{
     private List<Vehicle> listofVehicles = 
             new List<Vehicle>();  // class Vehicle

     public void AddVehicle(Vehicle v) { listofVehicles.Add(v); }
}
```

> also don't see why i'd need to create additional collection classes for 
>   containing `Motobike : Vehicle`

You don't :

```
var garage = new MyPlainVehicleCollection();
garage.Add(new Motobike ());
```

Comment: So what does the <Vehicle> do in the class definition line? i.e. what does it tell the compiler? Can it just be left out?

Comment: `<Vehicle>` is a Type parameter. Dangerous to use the same name as a class. Write your 2nd sample with `<V>` to see what happens better.

Comment: "Can it just be left out?" - that's never the same. Sometimes it _has to be_ left out.

Comment: The generic "type" doesn't have to be named `T`. In your second example it is named `Vehicle`, which just happens to be the same name as the class. Still is is a generic collection, but without any restriction on the type. Instead of `Vehicle` in your second sample you could also write `Bratwurst` and it would have the same effect.

Comment: I see, so the type parameter has no relation to the class name...but then in your example the List<Vehicle> is strongly typed to accept only Vehicles? i.e. type parameter is related to the Class Vehicle (in List<>) whilst it not if written in my example as its treated as the type parameter?

Comment: OK think i get it...but then as above, removing the <Vehicle> changes the meaning of List<Vehicle> significantly?

Comment: You're mixing up implementation and use of a generic class. The `listOfVehicles` in the sample without type parameter is declared as `List<Vehicle>`. This is using the generic class `List<T>`. So as your class `MyPlainVehicleCollection` is not generic, `Vehicle` in this case refers to the `Vehicle` class. You can add all descendants of the `Vehicle` class. If you added the type parameter `<Vehicle>` to your class definition again, `List<Vehicle>` would also refer to this type parameter. As there's not restriction on the type parameter, you'd basically end up with `List<object>`.

Answer (score 1):

You would generally use it to enforce the types accepted by your class - as long as they derive from Vehicle.

If you have

```
class Truck : Vehicle {}
```

and

```
class Van : Vehicle {}
```

You can declare

```
var x = new MyVehicleCollection<Truck> ();
```

Then the following would result in a compiler error :

```
x.AddVehicle ( new Van () );
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is not at runtime but at compile time.

In the first case you can only declare MyVehicleCollection with types that are Vehicle or derived from Vehicle.

In the second case you can declare MyVehicleCollection with any type as @Henk Holterman already said.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider not only class declaration, but also method (*may be* in this way it will be clearer)

```
//somewhere in the code have a method
public static string GetVehicleName<T>(T vehicle)  where T : Vehicle, new()
{
    return vehicle.GetVehicleName();
}

//abstract class Vehicle
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public abstract string GetVehicleName ();
}

//Child class 
public class Car : Vehicle
{  
   public override string GetVehicleName()
   {
     return "Car";
   }
}
```

and after use it, like

```
GetVehicleName(new Car()); //will return "Car"
```

This is not production ready code, just an example to give you, hope, an idea.

It bascially creates and abstraction layer for a function that can host *any* type of `Vehicles`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You example doesn't show the benefit necessarily.  Say, for example, you created a super new type of data structure that contains child lists:

```
public SuperFastForwardOnlyList<T> : where T : IEnumerable
{
    public void AddList(T childList);

    //Crazy new algorithm here that is going to earn you a fortune, but must use collections     
    //of the same type.
}
```

You can then use this with any type of enumerable, ensuring that it meets the constraints for your algorithm:

```
SuperFastOnlyList<IList> listOfLists = new SuperFastOnlyList<IList>();

listOfLists.Add(new List());  //Fine
listOfLists.Add(new object()); //Whoops - compile time error.
```

This example is also a little contrived, but might be more illuminating?